# Reading line by line from a socket

Tags: java, c, sockets

I am sending lines through a socket from a client in C, and reading on a server in Java. The best I can manage is that the client send the multiple lines, and when I close the client the server prints all the data in one line. Or to make it that one send then receives, etc. My desire is that the C application sends "Hi" in a loop, and the Java files catches first hi, prints and then catches second and prints. Right now it prints "HiHiHiHi...", but only when the connection is terminated.

I am using [oracle socket example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html) as guideline and using another  [guide](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm) for the C client

So reading the socket in Java is:

```
try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("Connected with client");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Accept failed.");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("RECEIVING " + inputLine);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        clientSocket.close();
        serverSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Connection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        out.close();
    }
```

Trying to write to the socket in a while loop the same string in C:

```
void connection(void) {
    int sockfd, portno;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct hostent *server;

    /* Set time limit. */
    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = 10;

    portno = 4444;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sockfd < 0) 
        error("ERROR opening socket");
    server = gethostbyname("Localhost");
    if (server == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR, no such host\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    bcopy((char *)server->h_addr, 
         (char *)&serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr,
         server->h_length);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
    if (connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
        error("ERROR connecting");
    while(1)    {
        /* Create a descriptor set containing our two sockets.  */
        FD_ZERO(&fds);
        FD_SET(sockfd, &fds);
        rc = select(sizeof(fds)*8, &fds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (rc==-1) {
            perror("select failed");
        }
            bzero(buffer,256);
            char *buffer2 = "here";

            n = write(sockfd,buffer2,strlen(buffer2));
            if (n < 0) 
                 error("ERROR writing to socket");

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I will edit to make it clear. Problem is how do I change the c code (almsot sure its here) so that my java file receives string and prints, string and prints.

Comment: You can check that it really is your C code by using Telnet on the client end and making sure the server is printing out lines you type one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is waiting for a \n before it prints anything.

Your client isn't sending any \n chars.

You might try:

```
char *buffer2 = "here"\n;
```

Comment: Thanks, the \n should be inside the " but apart from that is good. I think my idea that "" put a null character at the end was enough, was wrong.